# Why can't I use TArray<string> as a class constant?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

When I try and use an array constant inside a class then I get the following error:

`[dcc32 Error] TestConstants.dpr(14): E2086 Type 'TArray<T>' is not yet completely defined`

The same code compiles fine when I use it as a global constant or when I use `array of string` instead of TArray. Is there a trick to getting this working?

```
program Project98;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TMyTestClass = class
  strict private
    const
      TEST_CLASS_CONSTANT: TArray<String> = ['1','2']; // <-- Error here
      TEST_CLASS_CONSTANT2: array of string = ['1','2']; // <-- No error
  end;

const
  TEST_GLOABL_CONSTANT: TArray<String> = ['3','4']; // <-- No error
  TEST_GLOBAL_CONSTANT2: array of string = ['3','4']; // <-- No error
begin
end.
```

Comment: If you declare the type outside of the class it works. `Type SArr = TArray<String>; type TMyTestClass = class const TEST_CLASS_CONSTANT: SArr = ['1','2'];`. If it is not reported at QP, please submit an error report. (Same error in Tokyo 10.2.3)

Comment: If the class is declared as `TMyTestClass<T>`, none of the declared constants will pass without compiler error E2086.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will add an error report.

Comment: It is even weirder. If the `type SArr = TArray<string>;` is in its own type section, i.e. `type SArr = ....; type TMyTestClass....` then it compiles. But if it is in the *same* type section, i.e.: `type SArr = ..; TMyTestClass = ...` then it doesn't. That is clearly a bug.

Comment: @Graymatter: Could you please post the QP number? Or shall I report it?

Comment: I reported it: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-21151

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, can you please add the case when the class is generic as in my 2nd comment above in your report.

Comment: @LURD: yes, I will take a look. If not, I'll report it extra.

Comment: @LURD: updated, see https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-21151 now.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Thanks, just got back to my PC at the office this morning and you have already taken care of it.